# How to retrieve a parameter passed to a perl script using system?

Tags: perl, parameters

I am using:

`system($script, @my_args);`

So, I have this code in script.pl file:

```
my $script = "anotherScript.pl";
@my_args = ("anArgument");
system($script, @my_args);
```

In anotherScript.pl file, how can I retrieve the arguments in `@my_args`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are received in `@ARGV`